# Theorem numbering in amsbook class

Tags: numbering, amsbook

I'm writing my thesis using the amsbook class. I would like to number theorems by

[Chapter.Section.counter of the Theorem].

If I use

`\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]`

it gives only [Chapter.counter of the Theorem]. If I use

`\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}`

it gives only [Section. counter of the theorem]

How can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`?

Comment: This gives only [section.counter of theorem]. I would like also to count the chapter

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{theorem}`.

Comment: @Bernard -- that should be the answer.  please add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer really belongs to @Bernard.

The chapter number can be added to the output theorem counter without forcing the chapter number to appear as part of the section number by this redefinition:

```
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}
```